# Is changing class name considered refactoring?

Tags: refactoring

To avoid confusion between the different names of parent classes and child classes, I decided to change the name of the parent class to something more suitable. When I commit this change, should the commit message on git start with "Refactor ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, renaming is considered an act of refactoring according to many people, including Martin Fowler, author of the book *[Refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/renameVariable.html)*.

For example:

From [Refactoring source code in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring):

> Renaming is a common operation related to refactoring source code

From [Rename refactorings | IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html):

> Renaming local variables or private methods can be done easily inline since only the limited scope is affected. Renaming classes or public methods could potentially impact a lot of files. Preview potential changes before you refactor.